# whats my android studio's problem?

Tags: android-studio

[image: The image]

first see the picture above please,

I can't read any articles and text and words while i install android studio ....i use ubuntu 32 bit

Comment: How did you install it? PPA or download and unpack from the Android Studio website?

Comment: Did you change the default fonts on the system? Can you tell me what is listed under your font settings?

Comment: I downloaded and unpack it from the official site, Sean......

Comment: Yes, i change the defualt font and choose my favorite font ......Did it occure for changing font default?

Comment: It's likely related to the font change.

Comment: Yeah man!..... i fixed it .....thank you Sean

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If that doesn't work I'd recommend switching back to the default elementary fonts.